# Can Einstein's hidden-variables idea explain a Bell-type experiment with only two measurement directions?

Tags: quantum-spin, bells-inequality

Can Einstein's hidden-variables idea explain a Bell-type experiment with only two measurement directions?

Let’s give Alice and Bob two choices – they can either measure their spin at 0 degrees or 180 degrees.
According to Einstein’s hidden variables, the particles have already made up their mind about whether or not they will be measured as spin up or down for each of these filters. Let’s pretend that Alice’s particle decides to be spin up for 0°, spin down for 180°,(and the opposite for Bob). We can write this as UD for Alice, and DU for Bob. For different combinations of measurements, Alice and Bob will find:

We can write this as UD for Alice, and DU for Bob. For different combinations of measurements, Alice and Bob will find:

- Alice measures 0°, Bob measures 0°: different spins
- Alice measures 0°, Bob measures 180°: same spin
- Alice measures 180°, Bob measures 0°: same spin
- Alice measures 180°, Bob measures 180°: different spins

So 2/4 of the time, Alice and Bob make different measurements. So for half of the time, if Einstein is right, a spin measured by Alice and Bob a random direction should be different. This is the same as measured.

Answer (score 3):

A successful hidden variable theory has to explain every experiment. Bell gave an example of an experiment, involving three measurement angles, that no local hidden variable theory can explain.

You've given an example of a different experiment that a local hidden variable theory can explain, but that isn't good enough, because that theory is ruled out anyway by its inability to explain Bell's experiment.

Comment: Are 3 or more measurement angles realistic?

Comment: @midvoor What do you mean by realistic? Aspect's experiment involved four polarizers (two on each side) at four different angles, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

Isn’t it strange that different measurement angles give different chances of having a different spin measured by Alice and Bob.

 1) 2 measurement directions:
2/4 =50% of the time

2)3 measurement directions 
5/9 = 55.5 % of the time

3)4 measurement directions 
10/16 =62.5 %of the time

Kind regards